# Correct string encoding in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, encoding

I have the following string in NodeJS:

```
'3&#xAA; Jornada: Resumen 2'
```

which should be shown as:

```
'3ª Jornada: Resumen 2'
```

I have been trying to convert it to another

```
decodeURIComponent(escape(myString))
```

but it did not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://gist.github.com/CatTail/4174511) code snippet, I finally managed to do it in the following way:

```
myString = myString.replace(/&#(x[0-9A-Fa-f]{2});/g, function(match, hex) {
    return String.fromCharCode('0' + hex);
});
```